# Import gdal error in Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

When I type `import gdal` I get this:

```
   import gdal

  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gdal.py", line 2, in <module>
    from osgeo.gdal import deprecation_warn

  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()

  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)

  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)

  File "/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libpoppler.71.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/libgdal.20.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

`conda list` returns:

```
gdal                      2.2.2            py36hd505dc6_1  
libgdal                   2.2.2                h3559a57_1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import it like this

```
from osgeo import gdal
```

And just a note. I noticed that you are using gdal 2.2.2, if you want the newest version (2.2.4) you can download gdal from conda-forge

```
conda install -c conda-forge gdal
```

Comment: `from osgeo import gdal` does the exact same thing.  I updated to 2.2.4 and it didn't resolve the issue.  If I don't activate my `python3` environment gdal imports fine, so it must be something with the environment

Comment: Weird it works for me on windows, just checked with a new environment. However my conda list is huge after only gdal installation. Does it not install dependencies like numpy and mkl?

Comment: My numpy version is 1.14.0 and my mkl version is 2018.0.1.